# VS Code auto format strange wrapping behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

This problem is driving me nuts. I've Googled and found lots of suggestions, but none are working for me. I have a perfect problem example for consideration.

I have three buttons, on three separate lines. When I auto format, two of them break into multiple lines. They're all fairly short - under 80 characters, so line wrap length shouldn't be an issue. I've set both the default HTML and Prettier line lengths to 0 and 10000 and tried to disable wrap attributes. The main difference I see between the items is that the first button has a **single attribute**, and the others have **two**.

I've checked my extensions - I have a lot of them, but there's no clue about any other interference with this issue. Here are some screenshots to illustrate my problem. Thanks in advance for any advice!

**Before Format**

[image: Before Format]

**After Format**

[image: After Format]

**HTML Settings**

[image: HTML Settings]

**Prettier Settings**

[image: Prettier Settings]

**Extensions**

[image: Extensions]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Attribute, "preserve-aligned" works for me.

[image]